# Can you use imaginary numbers in calculus problems

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}\;\text{d}x= \arctan(ix) + C$$

Is it possible to use imaginary numbers in a regular interval like this, or should I separate them into real and imaginary parts?
Thx

Comment: See $$ \int \frac{1}{1+(a x)^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \arctan{(ax)} + \mathrm{C} $$

Comment: It's besides the point, but $(\arctan(ix))'\ne \frac1{1-x^2}$ by any means.

Comment: Also, $\tan^{-1}(ix) = i \tanh^{-1}x$

Comment: Most people who try this trick have no idea what the arctan of a complex number means. So the answer is "Sometimes you can, if you know what you're doing. But you probably don't know what you're doing."

Comment: @JonathanZ "In mathematics you don't understand things, you just get used to them"~John Von Neumann

Comment: If you knew holomorphic functions you could, but I doubt you know the extension of arctan to $\mathbb{C}$ is. Use $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2(1-x)} + \frac{1}{2(1+x)}$ instead

Comment: John Von Neumann knew what he was doing. I have my doubts about some of the people posting here.